# How to Extract data from xml column in sql 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

I have a table with a column of type xml. I have to extract the values from the xml column. I have tried all possible ways and i couldn succeed.Please find below the sample of the xml data.

```
<Menu>
  <Id>1</Id>
    <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-1.jpg</Url>
</Menu>
<Menu>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-2.jpg</Url>
</Menu>
<Menu>
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-3.jpg</Url>
</Menu>
<Menu>
  <Id>4</Id>
  <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-4.jpg</Url>
</Menu>
<Menu>
  <Id>5</Id>
  <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-5.jpg</Url>
</Menu>
```

Please help me to extract the data. Tons of thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Darthick.
s.darthick@gmail.com

Comment: go through these links [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148197/extracting-data-from-xml-in-sql-server-column]and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070256/the-best-way-to-extract-data-from-xml-with-xquery]

Comment: That does not appear to be XML data ;-). Please post the actual XML, or a snippet of it, and tell us what elements you need to extract.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @T table
(
  XMLCol xml
)

insert into @T values
('<Menu>
    <Id>1</Id>
      <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-1.jpg</Url>
  </Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-2.jpg</Url>
  </Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-3.jpg</Url>
  </Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-4.jpg</Url>
  </Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <Url>http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-5.jpg</Url>
  </Menu>')

select X.N.value('Id[1]', 'int') as Id,
       X.N.value('Url[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Url
from @T as T
  cross apply T.XMLCol.nodes('/Menu') as X(N)
```

Result:

```
Id          Url
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
1           http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-1.jpg
2           http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-2.jpg
3           http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-3.jpg
4           http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-4.jpg
5           http://www.zmtcdn.com/menus/1211/menu-photo-for-barbeque-nation-5.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is namespace. XML:

```
<PersonInfo xmlns="http://mynamspace.lv/default">
    <Person ID="22">
        <Name>MyName</Name>
        <Profession>MyProfession</Profession>
    </Person>
</PersonInfo>
```

Then you should do something like this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://mynamspace.lv/default')
SELECT
    @myXML.value('(PersonInfo/Person/@ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as ID,
    @myXML.value('(PersonInfo/Person/Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Name,
    @myXML.value('(PersonInfo/Person/Profession)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Profession;
```