# MS SQL 2008 - How do I convert xml value into a collection of rows from a ms sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a value in my MS SQL table column called "XDATA" like this:

```
<root><KV><Key>1</Key><Value>A</Value></KV>
    <KV><Key>2</Key><Value>B</Value></KV>
    <KV><Key>3</Key><Value>C</Value></KV></root>
```

I want to be able to get the value of the row back like this:

```
KEY, VALUE
1,A
2,B
3,C
```

So far I have written this:

```
DECLARE @a1  xml
    declare @x xml;
    set @x = '<root><KV><Key>1</Key><Value>A</Value></KV>
        <KV><Key>2</Key><Value>B</Value></KV>
        <KV><Key>3</Key><Value>C</Value></KV></root>';
   SELECT @a1 = @x.query('(/root/KV/Key/text())')
   select @a1
```

But I am getting 123 back.  Not three rows with two columns.  How do I get three rows back, each row with two columns:

```
KEY, VALUE
    1,A
    2,B
    3,C
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to shred the XML to rows and use [value()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to get a value.

```
select 
  T.N.value('Key[1]', 'int') as [Key],
  T.N.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Value
from @x.nodes('/root/KV') as T(N)
```

Comment: great.  what if instead of having @x, i wanted column of a table e.g. Data column of table Information?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - You put the table in the `from`clause and do a `cross apply` against the XML column. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9600806/569436)